# Deleting a file object from a library

Tags: files, libraries, ar

I've created a library with 3 file objects using:

```
ar rv arhiva.a file.o file2.o file3.o
```

Why I can't delete a file object from it? I've used

```
ar xv arhiva.a file.o
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from ar(1) man page

```
   d   Delete modules from the archive.  Specify the names of modules to be
       deleted as member...; the archive is untouched if you specify no files to
       delete.

       If you specify the v modifier, ar lists each module as it is deleted.
```

have you tried .. ?

```
 ar dv arhiva.a file.o
```

- x stand for eXtract
- you can copy/paste line, just make four white to have indentation ..